# MVC Passing Model Data to Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, canvas

Me and a friend have to make a canvas where you can drag images on. These images have to be loaded from a database.

This is our model Tafel:

```
public class Tafel{

    public int TafelId { get; set; }

    public int ReservatieId { get; set; }

    public string ImagePostion { get; set; }   

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? Tijd { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Datum { get; set; }

    public string Afbeelding { get; set; }

    public bool Beschikbaarheid { get; set; }
}
```

The canvas `position` is stored in `ImagePosition`. Here the canvas coordinates get stored.

Here we load the images on the canvas:

```
<script>
    var position = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImagePostion));

    var path = "somerandomimage.jpg";

    var canvas = $("#Canvas");
    var c = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

    var image = new DragImage(path, 50, 50);

    var loop = setInterval(function () {

        c.fillStyle = "gray";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

        image.update();

    }, 30); `
    //some drag & drop code after this
 </script>
```

So the `imagePosition` has to go on `DragImage(path, 50, 50)`.
We have tried to get the position by using `Json.Encode`, but it returns null.

Could anyone of you help me out how we are supposed to get the data out of the model into Javascript?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: What does the value of ImagePosition look like?

Comment: @Stuart 217/217 or 50/50. (Those are the canvas coordinates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `ImagePosition` value being in this format `number/number` you could split it out into an array and access the parts you need using an index

```
var position = '@Model.ImagePostion'.split('/');

// then access the values like so
var image = new DragImage(path, position[0], position[1]);
```

You might need to `parseInt` the values if the DragImage is expecting numbers and not strings.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer.
Getting this error now: 
`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[BonTempsRestaurant.Models.Tafel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BonTempsRestaurant.Models.Tafel'.`

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I am guessing you're passing a list of your model into the template (from the controller action) where your template is expecting a single instance of your model (`@model BonTempsRestaurant.Models.Tafel` - is this at the top of your template?)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. And yes that is above my view.

Comment: I managed to fix this part, now your code returns a `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Its workign now. I changed some stuff. But your code is working. Thanks for your help!